# I can't update anymore with the AppCenter

Tags: updates, applications, appcenter, error

when ever I try to install any application in AppCenter the following error occurred
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. Have done nothing special, installing, deleting or anything else besides the updates in AppCenter every now and then.
So what to do?

Edit:
Seems to only affect the system apps, like AppCenter, Files, etc (see the list in OP's image). Krita and Evolution updated fine from AppCenter.